# ¿Como puedo consumir una url encriptada en react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, url, jsx

se tiene la url encriptada, tengo la llave secreta pero cuando la abro en el navegador sale una codificacion enorme ese codigo esta encriptado y quiero desencriptarlo y mostrar la informacion en consola o en el navegador (ya busque e intente hasta con IA pero me marca errores en muchas cosas desde usar fetch hasta usar axios ya implemente metodos) entonces busco algun metodo o codigo que pueda realizar eso mostrar lo encriptado de una url

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';
import axios from 'axios'; // Si necesitas realizar solicitudes HTTP

const secretKey = 'llave_que tengo';
const encryptedUrl ='url_que_tengo_encriptada';

const decryptedUrl = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encryptedUrl, secretKey).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);

const EncuestasPublicas = () => {

  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Llamada a la función para obtener los datos cuando se monta el componente
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(decryptedUrl);
      const data = await response.json();
      setData(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error al obtener los datos:', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Resultados:</h1>
      <ul>
        {data.map((item) => (
          <li key={item.id}>{item.name}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );

    
};


export default EncuestasPublicas;
```

este coidigo es lo que se lleva investigando desde videos hasta ia, pero no logro visualizar lo que contiene esa url

alguien podria ayudarme a guiarme